# Spring Transactional propagation between nested methods

Tags: spring, transactions, annotations

I have the next question. If we have such architecture with appropriate Spring anootation:

```
method_parent() { - starts new transaction and after return commit
    method_child_1() {} - starts its own new transaction and after return commit
(A)
    method_child_2() {} - starts int own new transaction and after return commit
}
```

And at point **(A)** **method_parent** throws exception and stops execution, what will be with result database state? I mean if **method_child_1** will be commited or rolled back to initial state even if commited with its own transaction?

Comment: It depends on the code. Post it. Where are the methods? How do they start and commit their transactions? How are they annotated?

Comment: It is sientific question. No code exists. Lets imagine - all methods are marked with REQUIRES_NEW tranaction annotation type.

Comment: Then again, it depends. Where are the methods located? Do you use the default proxy-based mechanism for AOP or AspectJ. This all has an impact on the answer.  If the code really does what you say it does in the question, then it's not a scientific question, but an English question: you're asking if the first transaction is committed after it has been committed. The answer is yes. Changes made during a committed transaction can't be rollbacked anymore. That's the definition of a commit.